# Unable to login to Rundeck after successful website load

Tags: docker, rundeck

I am running 4.x.x version of Rundeck community on ECS. The docker image is hosted in our own ECR customized for adding utilities. I have a realm.properties file defining the credentials for different users and secrets for DB stored in the secretsmanager. This setup is working completely fine.

I am migrating this over to EKS and modified just the docker image with 5.x.x version. I have created secrets in the same EKS cluster and namespace. The rundeck URL webpage is loading fine but unable to login with any of the credentials defined in the realm.properties file.

I also tried the default `admin/admin` login but that doesn't work too.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG RUNDECK_IMAGE
FROM ${RUNDECK_IMAGE}
COPY data/realm.properties /home/rundeck/server/config
COPY data/plugins/. /home/rundeck/libext
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
    gnupg2 \
    jq \
    iputils-ping \
    sharutils \
    telnet \
    unzip \
    vim
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && sudo ./aws/install
```

I see this on the Chrome devtools console - `Refused to send form data to 'https://rundeck.xx.dev/j_security_check' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'.`

**Container log:**

```
INFO  web.requests "GET /user/login" 10.x.x.x http  form 2 ? [] (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome
INFO  web.requests "GET /static/images/favicon.ico" 10.x.x.x http  form 1 ? [image/x-icon] (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit
```

The webpage just keeps loading.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the service.log output (container log) at the moment of logging in?

Comment: Please add that on the original question. It seems you're facing this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8199. Try the following env vars in your Rundeck container definition: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8199#issuecomment-1475930318

Comment: Sure, will give that a try.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick but now I am getting `Invalid username and password.`

`admin/admin` didn't work as well as the credentials I have set in the `realm.properties` file>

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: 1- Check that the file (realm.properties) is present inside the container, also check that the format must follow this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#propertyfileloginmodule. 2- Also make sure that you're not calling an LDAP config. Could you put the full service.log output (not the chrome dev console output)? In docker environments, that content is the container log, check this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/

Comment: Confirmed that `realm.properties` is present under `/home/rundeck/server/config` in the container and follows the format. But it is encrypted, is that a problem?

The container log remains the same:
` INFO  web.requests "GET /health" 10.x.x.x http  form 0 ? [text/html;charset=utf-8] (kube-probe/1.27+)`

Comment: Could be. That the issue persist if you try with a "nonencrypted" realm.properties file? Please open a new question for this.

Comment: It was encrypted in the ECS way of deployment and didn't cause any issue. I am encrypting it because we store this in a SCM.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k New question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875601/encrypted-realm-properties-file-not-working-with-eks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these env vars in your Rundeck container definition

```yaml
      env:
        - name: RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL
          value: https://<url>:<port>
        - name: RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED
          value: "true"
```

[Same issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8199#issuecomment-1475930318).