# Encrypted realm.properties file not working with EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, rundeck, mozilla-sops

I am using `sops` to encrypt the `realm.properties` file which has the credentials for users to login to Rundeck. It is working on the ECS mode of deployment but seeing a `Invalid User and Password.` error when deployed on the EKS platform.

Can I `sops` encrypt the realm.properties file? I would like to, because I am committing this file to SCM.

Any thoughts on this?

Reference - [Unable to login to Rundeck after successful website load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77874698/unable-to-login-to-rundeck-after-successful-website-load),

Comment: Not sure how SOPS works but if you can try to deploy that without that tool to discard any base rundeck problem would be great. Also, please add the Rundeck deploy file (are you using a docker-compose file to define the env vars?)

Comment: Can I use any other encryption method to encrypt that file? In order to deploy, I need to commit that file to the SCM.

I have a dockerfile to build the image and GitHub action to deploy it.

Comment: Internally rundeck needs that file without encryption. Did you try without encryption? (just to discard a problem from the rundeck side). Anyway, the recommended way to manage users is to use LDAP (LDAPS in your case: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#communicating-over-secure-ldap-ldaps).

Comment: Tried it without encryption. Same issue persists. `realm.properties` isn't encrypted and follows the format as you mentioned. I see a `login_success` in the logs but it's still indefinitely loading the webpage.

```INFO  audit.AuditLoggerPlugin - Audit Event: AuditEvent {Timestamp=Wed Jan 24 21:38:28 GMT 2024, ActionType='login_success', UserInfo={username='admin', userRoles=[admin, user]}, RequestInfo={serverHostname='rundeck-xxx-xxx',}```

Do you suggest something else?

Comment: Is your `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` env var pointing to the final Rundeck URL endpoint? This could be the cause. Something like `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://mydomain:4440`. Take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7777#issuecomment-1176789898 (also test on Firefox, this kind of issue usually happens on Chrome or when you configure Rundeck behind a proxy server).

Comment: I am using configmap and secrets to pass these env_vars to the pod. I can see that `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` is set to `https://rundeck.xx.xx:4440`. Same issue persists with Mozilla as well.

Comment: Would I be able to get rid of this `realm.properties` file if I implement SSO with Okta?

Comment: Yes, also if you decide to use LDAP/LDAPS/AD. However, the OKTA integration is only for Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise").

Comment: I can't use Okta for Rundeck community? We are planning to just stick with community. How different it would be to do the AD thing?

Comment: OKTA is only for Process Automation. Regarding AD, check the doc entry here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/getting-started/users-overview.html#ldap-active-directory-integration

Comment: That's sad. Is there a future plan to bring Okta SSO to community?

Comment: Currently not. You can open a request here: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues

Comment: Thank you! So, how do I resolve the actual error?

Comment: That kind of error is caused mainly by rundeck headers/proxy config (are you using a proxy/web server solution in front of rundeck?) Please add more details on your original question (how are you deploying? the docker definition, etc). If you can test in other non-prod environments with and without the (potential) proxy would be great. The objective is to discard any external app issues. Another tip: take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7717#issuecomment-1781221813 it seems a similar issue.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Seems like the jobs inside this EKS Rundeck are working. There are cronjobs that triggered. It's just the login isn't working for some reason.

There's no non-prod environments. It's just direct deployment to a prod env. `X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` where should this go?

Comment: Removed port from `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` and it worked. I am logged in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `realm.properties` should be present in the container without the encryption. Also, for EKS deployment, port 4440 is not required for `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL`.